# How can I extend a class from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I wrote a gem with some basic logic that I wanted to share.  I publish it, install it, use it.

There are additional functions which I think are case-specific to my project.  I want to add additional methods using the same class name because it's familiar and everything is easy for me to keep track of mentally.

How can I install a gem, then add methods to it without conflict?  I have in the past overwritten methods defined in gems (notably Devise methods), but never tripped upon needing to expand the class itself.

Answer (score 12):

You just [open the class and add methods](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html). If you know the name of the class and where it is in the module hierarchy, then you just create another file that defines the same class and start adding methods. Since it's the same class name the methods will get added to the other class.

It's probably similar to what you did with Devise.

So if I have class `Bar` in a gem, and it's inside a module called `Foo`

```
# in the gem
module Foo
  class Bar
    def foobar
      'foobar!'
    end
  end
end
```

To add a method called `baz` to this class, without modifying the gem source code, then in your application just create a new file, declare the class inside its module again, and start adding stuff.

```
# in some other file in your app
module Foo
  class Bar
    def baz
      'foobar baz!'
    end
  end
end

 > f = Bar.new
 > f.foobar
=> 'foobar!'
 > f.baz
=> 'foobar baz!'
```

Since there can only be one copy of a class of a given name per module, then simply declaring the class again adds functionality to the existing class.

If you want to instead give some new class the `baz` method without changing the functionality of all `Bar` object instances in your app, then extend `Bar` instead. This will have the effect that your new class will have all `Bar` functionality, **plus** the new functionality, without modifying the functionality of `Bar` instances you may be using elsewhere in your app.

```
class NewClass < Foo::Bar
  def baz
    'foobar baz!'
  end
end

 > nc = NewClass.new
 > nc.foobar
=> 'foobar!'
 > nc.baz
=> 'foobar baz!'
```

Comment: Prior to posting my question, this is precisely what I tried.  I have a gem with a class called 'ZW' and I created a new file in my models dir called 'zw.rb' with 'class ZW' at the top to explicitly match.  I tried to add new methods into my zw.rb file inside my models dir.  Rails complained that 'zw has no such method'.  I had restarted rails (though I don't think I should have to).  It didn't work.  The only difference is you use module and I don't.  Is a module declaration required in a gem?  Obviously not because my gem works without it, but something is off

Comment: No, I was just showing an example with a module. If might be helpful if you post the code (or a link to it if it's public) so we can be on the same page. This definitely should work, so let's look at your actual code example and figure out what's happening.

Comment: I would just suggest to require the original class file on top to make sure it's loaded. (had some issues with that before)